# Would a moving elementary particle follow the Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle with respect to itself?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

An observer at rest or in motion different from the particle cannot determine its momentum and position to great accuracy at the same time. But what if the observer is on the particle itself or moving with the same velocity as the particle?

Comment: Although one can argue about the wording, this question you he's on an interesting fundamental issue and should not be closed.

Answer (score 2):

As elementary particles are point particles, there cannot be an observer "on them" . The only observation can happen with interactions with other particles, and yes, the envelope of the Heisenberg uncertainty has to be obeyed, whether the system is at rest ( studied in its center of mass) or moving.

In mathematical calculations, the interaction is calculated with [Feynman diagrams](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html) and the result is the probability distribution for the interaction happening, which it itself carries the HUP.

Comment: I've upvoted Anna's answer, but I thought it might be of interest to the OP that General Relativity (published 1915) differs from Einstein-Cartan Theory (completed in 1929), which requires that fermions have a (tiny) spatial extent.  Both theories are, I believe, considered "mainstream", and ECT's assumption about fermions (which has never been disproven) remained common in pop-sci texts at least into the 1960's.  Because of modifications by Sciama & Kibble, the most recent version of ECT's known as ECSK.

Comment: Utilization of ECT seems to vary culturally, heavier in slavic- and French-speaking regions and lighter in English-speaking ones, perhaps because of overly-facile interpretations of the Borde-Guth-Vilenkin Theorem (much-discussed on this site) in the latter.

Answer (score 0):

An electron feels its own field, which gives an infinity that has to be accounted for by renormalization. From this it is clear that the uncertainty relation does not apply to self interaction in QED.